dynamically change label in filament: laravel, php
I want to change the label:
Actual result:
Displayed “Remove from creators”  button (like during deleting several creators)
Expected result:
only “Trash can” button displayed
count($records) === 1 ? __('Trash can') : __('Remove from creators');
// bulkActions -> DeleteBulkAction -> label
class CreatorResource extends Resource
{
    protected static ?string $model = User::class;

    protected static ?string $navigationIcon = 'heroicon-o-paint-brush';

    protected static ?string $navigationLabel = 'Creators';

    protected static ?string $label = 'Creators';

    protected static ?string $slug = 'authors';

    public static function table(Table $table): Table
    {
        return $table
            ->modifyQueryUsing(static function ($query) {
                $query->leftJoin('model_has_roles', 'model_has_roles.model_id', '=', 'users.id')
                    ->where('model_has_roles.role_id', '=', UserRole::CREATOR->value);
            })
            ->columns([
                TextColumn::make('name')
                    ->searchable()
                    ->sortable(),
            ])
            ->actions([
                Action::make('trash')
                    ->label('')
                    ->icon('heroicon-o-trash')
                    ->action(static function (User $user) {
                        return $user->removeRole(UserRole::CREATOR->value);
                    }),
            ])
            ->bulkActions([
                DeleteBulkAction::make()
                    ->successNotificationTitle(__('Removed'))
                    ->label(__('Remove from creators')) 
                    ->modalHeading(__('Remove users'))
                    ->modalSubmitActionLabel(__('Yes, remove it'))
                    ->action(static function (Collection $records) {
                        $records->each(static function ($user) {
                            assert($user instanceof User);
                            $user->removeRole(UserRole::CREATOR->value);
                        });
                    }),
            ]);
    }

    public static function getPages(): array
    {
        return [
            'index' => Pages\ListCreators::route('/'),
        ];
    }
}

I tried use ternary operation and callback in my label.

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

This: count($records) === 1 ? __('Removed one creator') : __('Removed creators'); is not stored to any value, so it is only an expression? ... what do you intend to do with either of those values?
